# Django INSTALLED_APPS not installed and preventing makemigrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, pip

I recently pulled a repo from GitHub to get a local copy on my machine. The backend uses Django, and I was working on updating some models. Since I changed some models I wanted to run `./manage.py makemigrations`. At first there was an issue with python2 vs python3, so I changed the `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Then when I ran makemigrations, I get this:

```
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'autofixture'
```

Looking a bit further, I found out that this is because my `settings.py` file has `autofixture`, `bootstrap3`, and `formtools` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but somehow my machine doesn't have those. I've tried to `pip install` all of them but the names autofixture, bootstrap3, and formtools aren't found in pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in pip, albeit not in those names; they are `django-autofixture`, `django-bootstrap3` and `django-formtools` respectively.

So you can install them by typing:

```
pip install django-autofixture django-bootstrap3 django-formtools
```

**Edit**: Use `pip3` instead of `pip` when using python3

```
 pip3 install django-autofixture django-bootstrap3 django-formtools
```